# Angular 1.5 :How to load controller specific js controllers when required

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js, I have started refactoring code in my project which was developed by some developers previously working in my organization. There are some problems in the code that is making my web page slow.

- There is a dashboard page with all the feature links over there. On click of each and every link the html is getting replaced with the specific feature. Now to make this happen the developers have included all the controller/service js file in the dashboard page itself, which is obviously making the page to load slow.

Please help me out or at-least give me a direction in which i should start thinking.

Comment: It looks like your problem is performance (slow). It is very hard to figure out what exactly makes your project to run slowly since this can be caused by many various things.  Including controller/service files not sounds the problem since it is commonly used practice in angular...

Comment: Ok, let me make it straight, can anybody give me the way to load a controller js file when required

Comment: i guess you can look at this lazyLoad modules lib :https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad/ (But i must note the thing you can load lazily here is module, not controller)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to optimize something that you are no investigated. 
You can use [oc-lazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/) package in order to achieve your requirements, but bare in mind that, it only improve the first bootstrap nothing else.

From your description, it looks like you have a different performance problem, you should investigate it using devtools performance tab.

Comment: I don't want to lazy load but want to lazy download

Comment: With `angular 1.5` it is not so trivial to do, ocLazyLoad allows you to lazy download + load.